# TPPDF - table cell at bottom of page cut off

Tags: swift

This is my first question on stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm missing anything.

I'm having a problem with a table cell being cut off at the bottom of the page when using the TPPDF cocoapod in a swift 4 app for i-pad.  Only part of the cell shows with no text

I'm creating a series of tables in my document.  Because the column widths are variable I'm adding a new table for each row.

Is there a way to either prevent this from happening or to determine when to add a page break?

[image]

Comment: I think that the best help that you would get is if you opened a ticket on the GitHub repo. because this seems like a bug. the owner of the repo is a really nice guy and will help you.

Comment: Thanks zombie.  I did that.  Is there a way I can mark this as question as answered?